# how to add options in select2 with loop and chained dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have this code like here, I want to add `<option>` to each select2, when I add dynamic input.

```js
$("#warehouse").change(function() {
  var id = $("#warehouse").val();
  var url = 'pipe_data.php?loc=' + id;
  var idf = $("#idf").val();
  var j, i;
  for (j = 1; j < idf; j++) {
    $("#pipe_name" + j).select2({
      placeholder: '-- Choose Pipe Name --',
      theme: "bootstrap",
      width: '100%'
    });
    $("#pipe_name" + j).html('');
    $("#pipe_name" + j).append('<option value="">-- Choose Pipe Name --</option>');
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result) {
        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          $("#pipe_name" + j).append('<option value="' + result[i].code + '">' + result[i].code + '|' + result[i].name + '|' + result[i].unit + '</option>');
        }
      }
    })
  }
});
```

in this code i have problem, `pipe_name` can't add in select2

Comment: What about this https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items?

Comment: BTW, You can declare the jQuery object once instead of calling to `$` again and again. Like this: https://gist.github.com/moshfeu/b934f5b2deec73e7fe7c56ae9eb0ad4f

Comment: Glad to hear :)